# When are argparse subparsers actually useful

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I know how to use argparse's subparsers to create a CLI that behaves something like this:

```
command subcommand-a --option-for-a-1 value --option-for-a-2 value
command subcommand-b --option-for-b-1 value
```

The idea in a typical use-case of subparsers is to create subcommands, each with their own set of options, then after parsing the arguments a function would be chosen based on the subcommand and the arguments would be passed to it.

My question is what was the point of creating the whole subparsers mechanism when I could achieve exactly the same thing (arguably in a much simpler fashion) doing something like this?

```py
# __main__.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from .foo import foo
from .bar import bar

COMMANDS = {
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar,
}

def get_args() -> tuple[Namespace, list[str]]
    parser = ArgumentParser("myprog")
    parser.add_argument(
        "subcommand",
        choices=list(COMMANDS.keys())
    )
    # add some more arguments as needed...
    parser.add_argument("-v", action="count")
    return parser.parse_known_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args, remainder = get_args()
    COMMANDS[args.subcommand](remainder)
```

```py
# foo.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def get_args(argv: list[str]):
    parser = ArgumentParser("myprog foo")
    # add all foo's options
    parser.add_argument("-f")
    return parser.parse_args(argv)

def foo(argv: list[str]):
    args = get_args(argv)
    print("You have chosen foo:", args)
```

```py
# bar.py
# same as foo, without loss of generality
```

I see a couple of additional benefits in using this approach.

The first is that by using parse_known_args in the main parser, it allows you to pass flags in any order regardless of the parser they belong to, for example all of these would be allowed:

```
myprog foo -f ./file.txt -vv
myprog foo -vv -f ./file.txt
myprog -vv foo -f ./file.txt
```

Whereas using subparsers, only the last one would be allowed, even though it seems natural for the user to expect it to work in all cases.

The second benefit I see is that it makes it more natural for the code for each subcommand (the declaration of the CLI as well as the code that uses the CLI input) to stay encapsulated in their own modules/classes/whatever. But when using subparsers, despite it being possible (albeit with a bit more acrobatics) to separate the creation of each parser, it tends to happen that there's one big function that declares the CLI for all subcommands, or at best that job is split into several functions but they are all in the same module/class.

In conclusion, the whole concept of subparsers to me seems like a trap which ultimately complicates the code more than just doing it yourself. Is there any actual benefit or appropriate use case where subparsers are actually a good idea?

Comment: a possible benefit of _argparse_ is to have a standard help message, `python myprog -h`

Comment: `add_subparsers` creates a specialized `positional` argument.  Most of the work is implemented in that `Action` subclass   The `__call__` of that class passes the parsing action to the named sub-parser.  It also implements the sub-parser help.  For a lot of users it's enough, but as you found with things like `parse_known_args` you can do a multistep parsing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I see there's a problem with my alternative implementation.

When passing -h it will always be caught by the root parser and it'll be impossible for the user to see the help of the subcommands, unless instead of parsing known args, the root parser adds an option with nargs="...", but that means the first benefit I pointed out is lost